# Maven tomcat 7 plugin Issues in Web service Deployment

Tags: java, web-services, maven, tomcat

We used maven tomcat 7 plugin for, deploy the war application. in our war application we are trying to connect to another web service. we got below exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: MASM0015: Class [ com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.HandlerTubeFactory ] does not implement [ com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.dev.TubeFactory ] interface
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.<init>(TubeCreator.java:63)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.initializeTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:116)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.getTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:79)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(MetroTubelineAssembler.java:103)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:328)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:295)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:228)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:243)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getStubHandler(WSServiceDelegate.java:814)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:803)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:436)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386)
```

we used java 8 and jax-rt-2.2.8.jar for build the web application.

We have changed our source code according to below.

```
Class provideClass = Class.forName( "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl");
provider = (Provider) provideClass.newInstance();
ServiceDelegate delegate = provider.createServiceDelegate( urlWsdl, new QName( namespaceURI, serviceName ), (Class<? extends Service>) bindClass );
QName qName = new QName( namespaceURI, portName );
WebServicesPT port;
port = ( WebServicesPT ) delegate.getPort( qName, bindClass );
```

When we use normal tomcat 8 and 7 server this code is working perfectly.

But Maven tomcat plugin gives above exception.

it seems jax.rt jar use for TubeFactory  implementation. it should be comes from jre/lib/rt.jar.

Any one support to me resolve this issue and highly appreciate your feedback :)

Comment: i couldn't get the error exactly. Is problem java version ? Or is it tomcat version ? Or is it your code ?

Comment: sercan-ozdemir : I have updated error :)

Comment: Can you try to add jaxws runtime environment into your pom.xml

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.2.7-promoted-b24

Comment: ya i have already added it as tomcat maven plugin dependency but same error is occurring.